Cascading DropDown with Form.io
I am using form.io to make a cascading dropdown, the select lists populate there data with URL like this JSON of the select list


   {
  "label": "Model",
  "widget": "choicesjs",
  "tableView": true,
  "dataSrc": "url",
  "data": {
    "resource": "66aa1469d01304bfc3bf4a3a",
    "url": "https://localhost:7252/api/FormJSON/Users",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "",
        "value": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "valueProperty": "roleId",
  "template": "<span>{{ item.name }}</span>",
  "refreshOn": "make",
  "clearOnRefresh": true,
  "validate": {
    "select": false
  },
  "validateWhenHidden": false,
  "key": "model",
  "type": "select",
  "disableLimit": false,
  "searchField": "data.model__regex",
  "filter": "{{data.roleId}}={{data.make.id}}",
  "noRefreshOnScroll": false,
  "input": true
}



I was expecting that the second select list will filtter the data by the first select value but I guess the filtter query isn't correct.
So any help
